# How do I correct for errors in smoothing plotted data? (final data point is shifted)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math

The final data point is shifted compared to the rest of the graph, included is a reference plot in green with no smoothing showing the intended final data point.

I have tried smoothing the data using other methods such as scipy.

```
import tkinter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m
import numpy as np

warmup = 30
starttemp = 120
waittime = 10
soaktime = 15
endtemp = 210
heatrate = 10 # x/min
one = 1

temprange = endtemp - starttemp
time = ((temprange//heatrate)*60) 
#time in seconds from start to end temp
y = list(range(1,warmup,1))
x = temprange/heatrate
wur = list(range(warmup, starttemp,1))
interval = int(temprange//time)
methtime = list(range(starttemp,endtemp,1))
#integrate heating rate functionality into the 
#projection graph by adding interval variable.

for _ in range(one):
    y.extend(wur)

for _ in range(soaktime):
    y.append(starttemp)

for _ in range(waittime):
    y.append(starttemp)

for _ in range(one):
    y.extend(methtime)

def smooth(y, box_pts):
    box = np.ones(box_pts)/box_pts
    y_smooth = np.convolve(y, box, mode='same')
    return y_smooth

#plt.plot(y,'g--')
plt.plot(smooth(y,15), 'r--', lw=1)
plt.ylabel('Temperature')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.title('PID Control Graph For Current Method')
plt.show()
```

The final data point should follow the general trend of the data and end at the correct end temperature.

How it should look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQfwK.jpg
how it currently looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hugb.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your box convolution function extends out of data range, so you see "edge effect". This is fundamental problem of convolution.

You can get shortened output range [with mode ‘valid’](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html)

Also you can repeat last data point several times (corresponding to box width) to minimize this effect and get full output range (padding with the last value instead of zeros)

Perhaps one more approach - apply "left-side" convolution function to the last entries if possible to join results.

Comment: Thanks, changing same to valid seemed to fix the problem!

    def smooth(y, box_pts):
        box = np.ones(box_pts)/box_pts
        y_smooth = np.convolve(y, box, mode='valid')
        return y_smooth